# store url parameter with php

Tags: php, url, dom, parameters, domdocument

i need to store an url parameter from a button using php (using DOMdocument?!)
the button on my website has a link url which contains an parameter

```
http://example.com/register/register-company.html?tx_powermail_pi1[regUid]=78
```

the way is to store the id 78 (from [regUid]=78), but the id is dynamic it can be 33, 23, or some other number. Is there any solution without jQuery and Javascript?

thx for any help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$link = "<a href='http://example.com/register/register-company.html?tx_powermail_pi1[regUid]=78'>Link</a>" ;
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($link);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node){
    $url = $node->getAttribute("href");
    $parts = parse_url($url) ;
    $query = $parts['query'];
    parse_str($query, $vars) ;
    echo $vars['tx_powermail_pi1']['regUid'] ;
}
```

Comment: but this does not find the link of my button with the parameter and i cant search for 78 because this number is dynamic...this number was only an example...

Comment: I got no idea what your button looks like and how to fetch it. Also, I do not know what do you mean by "dynamic".

Comment: the button is simple a: span with an a tag (link) <span><a title="mytitle" href="http://example.com/register/register-company.html?tx_powermail_pi1[regUid]=78">mybutton<a></span> and the number from regUid comes from a database it depends on a newspost, the goal is to store this id to a variable in php to work with queries.